# Ajax calls to server are not getting triggered

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am currently unable to get angular-dataTables to request data from the server.

When I use `.fromFnPromise()` it works fine. My code is called and then I call my service to get the data.

```
  vm.dtOptions = dataOptionBuilder.fromFnPromise(
        service.getViewItems()
               .then(function(data) {
                     vm.logs = data;
                });
     )
     .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
     .withDisplayLength(25);
```

However, I now need to do server-side paging, so I'm using `.withOptions()` and passing in the ajax options:

```
    vm.dtOptions = dataOptionBuilder.newOptions()
                                    .withOption('ajax', {
                                        url: '/api/services/app/patients/GetViewItems',
                                        type: 'POST'
                                    })
                                    .withDataProp('data')
                                    .withOption('serverSide', true)
                                    .withOption('processing', true)
                                    .withOption('order', [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc']])
                                    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

View

```
<table id="dt_basic" datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-class="expand"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lock"></i>Comment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.logs">
            <td>{{ item.comment }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I based this code on a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MksjdyLmMxCG1FjSUEmo?p=info) from the author  [l-lin](https://github.com/l-lin).

Any idea on why it is not triggering an AJAX request?

Comment: The ajax request is being triggered. The problem is that the HTML is not being update for some reason, I couldn't find why. You can see the requests by pressing F12 on Chrome and going to Network tab.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this plugin: http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `datatables` reference guide, `.withOption('serverSide', true)` means that you are responsible for implementing [paging on your server](http://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide).

Rather than specify the path to an ajax service, you can [use a function](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#function) to call your angular service with the information necessary for paging (as well as filtering and sorting).

```
.withOption('ajax', function(data, callback, settings) {
  //pass the data parameter to your service to access necessary paging info
  service.getViewItems(data)  
   .then(function(result) {
       callback(result);
    });
})
```

Here is a demo of hooking your service into the option builder: http://plnkr.co/edit/1V9qdpO47XBFtGVV6j2I?p=preview